# Trying to figure out this 2 ETH smart contract quiz

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security, contract-debugging

Does anyone know whether this smart contract can be broken? Is there some trick behind this?

https://etherscan.io/address/0xfc62a32da21052fb3086e8f68ad10a7118a98606

Comment: Why would anybody publicly post the solution if they find it? Please, rephrase your question in such a way that you're asking it from a technical, intellectually-curious perspective.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a good exercise to understand some details of how ethereum works.

The whole thing is a "scam". The two people who send the ether never had a chance.

The thing attracts attention because the contract code shows that the answer is submitted and then the hash of it is calculated. If you see the transaction after the contract creation, the answer appears to be 'g00gol', which is what the people tried to submit to the contract.

**This is what is happening:**

A contract at `0x7472bfa8924073180ee288d32246f5a850e8bd93` is deployed. You can get this because this is the address stored in the contract with the variable `questionSender` (2th slot). This contract code is not available but from the bytecode you can see that `start_game` is called and then 'NewQuestion' is also called, note that `NewQuestion` do not submit the answer but the hash of it.

Then a transaction is submitted calling `start_game`, with the question and the answer (g00gol) but this do not fulfill the condition: `responseHash==0x0` because a question has already been sent through an "internal transaction".
The 2 Ethers are stored but the _response is not modified.

So the response is not g00gol and unless you break `keccak256`, the answer will never be known.

**So do not put your money there and let others know.**

**Note1**: The guy who make this has a sense of humor, the hash of the answer is in the slot 3 of the storage, and is : `0x77686f206b6e6f77730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
if you look for the ascii of this hex number, (remove the zeros) you get the words: **'who knows'**.

**Note2: The OP could be the victim or the scammer itself trying to get attention to his game.**

Hope this helps.